# Operation on one data frame changes another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why does this code:

```
df2 = df1
df2['sources'] = df2['sources'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
```

also change `last_seen_ip` itself? `df1` and `df2` always look the same after the code execution and the `.join()` part stretches out the column further each time.

Why is this? Thank you

Comment: Because `df2` and `df1` are 2 names pointing to the same object. Use `df2 = df1.copy()`